# Appending character to a 'db' variable in masm assembly

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86, masm

I have just started learning assembly, and I am stuck.
I have a character in a `WPARAM` variable ( can also be `DWORD` ), and I have to append it to a `db` string. I have no idea as to how to do it.
Here is my code:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none

WinMain proto :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD

include C:\Program Files\masm32\include\windows.inc
include C:\Program Files\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include C:\Program Files\masm32\include\user32.inc
include C:\Program Files\masm32\include\gdi32.inc


includelib "C:\Program Files\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib"
includelib "C:\Program Files\masm32\lib\user32.lib"
includelib "C:\Program Files\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib"

.data
cn db "Parth",0
an db "Priydarshi Singh",0
char WPARAM 21h
text db "A",0
ps DWORD ?
hin HINSTANCE ?
cmd LPSTR ?

.code
start:
    invoke GetModuleHandle, 0
    mov hin, eax
    invoke GetCommandLine
    mov cmd, eax
    invoke WinMain, hin, 0, cmd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

    WinMain proc inst:HINSTANCE, pinst:HINSTANCE, cml:LPSTR, show:DWORD

        LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX
        LOCAL msg:MSG
        LOCAL hwnd:HWND

        mov wc.cbSize, sizeof WNDCLASSEX
        mov wc.style, CS_VREDRAW or CS_HREDRAW
        mov wc.lpfnWndProc, offset WndProc
        mov wc.cbClsExtra, 0
        mov wc.cbWndExtra, 0
        push hin
        pop wc.hInstance 
        mov   wc.hbrBackground,COLOR_WINDOW+1 
        mov   wc.lpszMenuName,NULL 
        mov   wc.lpszClassName,OFFSET cn 
        invoke LoadIcon,NULL,IDI_APPLICATION 
        mov   wc.hIcon,eax 
        mov   wc.hIconSm,eax 
        invoke LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW 
        mov   wc.hCursor,eax 
        invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc

        invoke CreateWindowEx, NULL, addr cn, addr an, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 1366, 750, NULL, NULL, inst, NULL

        mov hwnd, eax
        invoke ShowWindow, hwnd, show
        invoke UpdateWindow, hwnd

        .WHILE TRUE
            invoke GetMessage, addr msg, NULL, 0, 0
            .BREAK .IF(!eax)
            invoke TranslateMessage, addr msg
            invoke DispatchMessage, addr msg
        .ENDW

        mov eax, msg.wParam
        ret

    WinMain endp

    WndProc proc hwnd:HWND, umsg:UINT, wp:WPARAM, lp:LPARAM

        LOCAL hdc:HDC
        LOCAL rect:RECT

        .IF umsg==WM_DESTROY
            invoke PostQuitMessage, 0

        .ELSEIF umsg==WM_CHAR
            push wp
            pop eax
            mov char, eax
            ; I need some code here to append 'char' to 'text' 
            invoke InvalidateRect, hwnd, NULL, TRUE

        .ELSEIF umsg==WM_PAINT
            invoke BeginPaint, hwnd, addr ps
            mov hdc, eax
            invoke TextOut, hdc, 0, 100, addr text, sizeof text
            invoke EndPaint, hwnd, addr ps

        .ELSE
            invoke DefWindowProc, hwnd, umsg, wp, lp
            ret

        .ENDIF

        xor eax, eax
        ret

    WndProc endp

end start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only append to a string if there's space available for additional characters.

You've declared `text` as `text db "A",0`, which reserves 2 bytes at `text` (`'A'` and `0`), so there's no room for additional characters. If you know the maximum length that the string ever will be you can still allocate it statically; for example `text db 1024 dup(0)` would give you 1024 bytes of space where all bytes have the initial value 0. If you have another variable that keeps track of the current number of characters in the string you can use that to append to the string:

```
mov edi,text_length
mov [text + edi],al
inc dword ptr text_length
```

If your string can shrink as well as grow you'll have to make sure to insert a NUL terminator at right place when you "remove" characters from the string.

If you don't know the maximum length of the string in advance, or if the maximum is very large, you can allocate memory dynamically with one of the memory allocation functions provided by Windows, e.g. [`HeapAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If the string is about to grow beyond the currently allocated size you increase the size of the allocated block with `HeapReAlloc` (e.g. to twice the size of the previous size).

Comment: But how do you store the value of `char` in al?

Comment: Seems to me like it's already in `al` since you're doing `mov char, eax`.  Remember that `al` is the least significant byte of `eax`.

Comment: Its just not working. Can you please tell me what's the mistake:

I have declared a variable **len** in `.data` section as: `len dd 0`

Also, I have changed the **text** declaration to `text db 1024 dup(0)`

And, in `.ELSEIF umsg==WM_PAINT` section, I have added :

`mov edi, len` ;    
 `mov [text+edi], al` ;     
`inc dword ptr len`

But it's not giving the desired output.

Comment: You're not supposed to append when you get the `WM_PAINT` message. You're supposed to do it when you get `WM_CHAR`.

Comment: db is "define byte", dw is "define word" and dd is "define dword". For a wParam, you would want to define a dword but they are 4-byte aligned so simply coding it to follow a series of bytes may not simply append it.

Comment: @Michael, I did it in `WM_CHAR`. Still its not working.

Comment: It works for me if I take the code from your question and just replace the line `mov char,eax` with `mov edi,len` / `mov [text+edi],al` / `inc dword ptr len` (with `len dd 0` added in the data section, and `text` declared as `text db 1024 dup(0)`).